# Inserting and deleting associated data in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I am still learning Ruby on Rails and ll of the related things so please bare with my limited knowledge. I have developed small a rails app for learning, which has user, habit, goal and milestone model. So, users can create a habit that they would like to develop, also add achievable goals to habit, and milestones to those goals so it can help users to stay focused.

Relationships between all of the models looks like these:

```
users

  has_many :habits
  has_many :comments
  has_many :goals, through: :habits
  has_many :milestones, through: :goals


habits
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :goals_habits
  has_many :goals, through: :goals_habits
  has_many :milestones, through: :goals

goals

 has_many :goals_habits
 has_many :habits, through: :goals_habits
 has_many :users, through: :habits

 has_many :goals_milestones
 has_many :milestones, through: :goals_milestones

goals_habits

  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :habit

milestones

  has_many :goals_milestones
  has_many :goals, through: :goals_milestones
  has_many :habits, through: :goals
  has_many :users, through: :habits

goals_milestones

  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :milestone
```

After creating habit, I also give user a drop down menu to select goals from. And same way, after creating goal, user can also select a milestone to add to goal from the given drop down menu. Goals and Milestones are already seeded into database and has below values:

```
goals = ["Should develop this in 1 week.", "Should develop this in 2 weeks.", "Should develop this in 3 weeks.", "Should develop this in 4 weeks." ]

milestones = ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 5", "Day 6", "Day 7", "Day 8", "Day 9", "Day 10", "Day 11", "Day 12", "Day 13", "Day 14",
"Day 15", "Day 16", "Day 17", "Day 18", "Day 19", "Day 21", "Day 22", "Day 23", "Day 24", "Day 25", "Day 26", "Day 27",
"Day 28", "Day 29", "Day 30", "Day 31 - The final day" "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4"]
```

Now the best way to explain bug is through example. So pardon me if this post gets too long.

Let's say that there are two users in database. `User A` and `User B`. Now, `User A` creates a habit `"Reading"`, then adds a goal `"Should develop this in 1 week."` `User A` also add `"Day 13"` milestone to the goal `"Should develop this in 1 week."`.

SO, now, if `user B` will add goal `"Should develop this in 1 week."` to his habit `"Swimming"`, goal `"Day 13"` will automatically assigned to it because user A assigned that milestone to his goal. Which I don't want.

The same thing will happen if one of them will destroy milestone from that goal. It will get deleted from both of the habits.

I want database to treat each request separately. I understand that it is happening because once a milestone is attached to a goal in database, it is going to show up every time. But I have no idea how to solve this.

I tried to assign milestones of goal to empty array while any user will try to create a new goal but as you may can predict it will do the same for all of the habits who may have that goal.

I think, I need to put some kind of conditions for inserting and deleting associated records in database but not sure what. Tried really hard to look for a solution but can't solve this problem. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the structure of your records & relations, you need to simplify it a bit.

"Goals" can't have multiple users, they should be something like

Goal has many milestones, belongs to one habit (& if needed belongs to user).
So when you create a "habit" for a "user", then you create a goal for that particular habit.
And the goal table should look something like:

- id,
- habit_id,
- user_id,
- target(or whatever describing the goal):string
  And the goal has_many milestones

With the milestone table looking something like:

- id,
- goal_id,
- completion_date:date

If you want to add milestones to things other than goals (like directly to habits) you could also and you should really think in which terms you'll be using the data. Because there's no need to create more complexity if in practical terms you'll only be adding milestones to goals, which doesn't even seem very logical right?

They kinda try to describe the same thing, "In x week" (a date in the future) and the milestone "In x day". So probably the habit should have both goals and milestones, but goals shouldn't have milestones, unless you change the goals to reflect something like "sub-tasks" of the habit itself.

And of course in this exercise it might not be very important, but thinking clearly about the ways in which you'll use the data and how it can go together is actually essential in correctly designing a DB structure and reducing complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @micael, I couldn't find any other way to solve this error. But making changes to my tables and Schema did solve the problem. Still curious to find another way around!